Почему в предложении пишется ели, а не елей? «Они чуть не цеплялись за верхушки ели.»
Диктант для третьего класса и там такое словосочетание.

Правильно: елей. Но написал этот диктант, видимо, не очень грамотный человек, потому и использовал форму единственного числа. А в Сеть, к сожалению, попадает много мусора… Вариант «(верхушки) ели» в таком предложении был бы возможен лишь в том случае, если бы у этой ели было несколько верхушек. Но об этом, думаю, ничего в диктанте не говорится.


Рано утром старик вышел из избушки. За одну ночь всё в природе
изменилось. Низкие облака ползли над самой землёй. Они чуть не
цеплялись за верхушки елей. Вид был печальный. В воздухе кружилась
живая сетка из мягких пушистых снежинок.
Д.Н. Мамин-Сибиряк “Серая
шейка”

